# how to know whether login is successfull or not?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests, robobrowser

I am using roboBrowser to login into a website and this the code

```
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser
browser = RoboBrowser(parser = "html5lib")
login_url = 'someUrl/login.php'
browser.open(login_url)
form = browser.get_form(id='form1')
form['Username'].value = "User"
form['Password'].value = "1234"
browser.submit_form(form)
```

I see here the form is submitted successfully.How can i know the login is successful,as it does not returns any response code as successful like in requests.get `<Response 200>`but in this case it doesn't return anything.so,how can i know the login is successful or not.

Comment: Can you access a protected page after?

Comment: I tried to `browser.open(protected page)`.but no idea how to proceed after.If i want to check the content of the page how to do that?

Comment: Per the HTTP spec, a 200 result code indicates success. Unfortunately, many "modern" authentication schemes effectivily operate at a higher layer, and the HTTP response by itself is uninformative. Without more information about the specific site you are accessing, we can only guess.

Comment: if guess if you can print the current url

Comment: @anderson,  you can get a 200 response and still not be authenticated depending on the site so that is not something to rely on, a simple method would be to check for something that will only be visible on the protected page.

Comment: @tripleee okay,Is there any way to get the content of the page?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes,is there any way to get the content of the page in robobrowser?

Comment: @anderson `browser.parsed`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham browser.parsed() parses the login_url in the above example.?If so how to parse the protected page

Comment: @anderson, then you are not logged in, after you submit `self._update_state(response)` is called just like it is with open so you should see what you see when successfully logged in or you get redirected back to the login page for unsuccessful logins.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham thankyou

Comment: @anderson, no worries, can you share the url?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham sorry,thats my university portal :p.thankyou that worked !!add an answer for upvote :)

Comment: @anderson, no prob,  you can add an answer yourself with what worked, it will be a bit more rep for you ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118748/discussion-between-anderson-and-padraic-cunningham).

Answer (score 1):

```
p = browser.parsed()
f = open("file.txt","w+",encoding = 'UTF-8')
f.write(str(p))
f.flush()
f.close()
```

you can find the username or some data which is visible only after login to confirm the login